# Lambda expression to find greatest among 3 numbers

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Background: I am trying to write a shortest possible lambda expression to find the greatest of 3 numbers.
Of course ternery operator is capable of doing it.

```
Func<int, int, int, int> greatestNumber2 = (x, y, z) => (x > y) ? ((x > z) ? x : z) : ((y > z) ? y : z);
```

But my intention is to achieve a function such as the one below.

```
greatest (x, y, z) = if (greater (x, y)>z) then greater(x, y) else z;
```

I was able to do this in two ways.

```
            Func<int, int, int> greaterNumber = null;
            Func<int, int, int, int> greatestNumber = null;

            //Expression 1
            greaterNumber = (x, y) => x > y ? x : y;
            greatestNumber = (x, y, z) => greaterNumber(x, y) > z ? greaterNumber(x, y) : z;

            //Expression 2
            greatestNumber = (x, y, z) => {
                Func<int, int, int> greater = (i, j) => i > j ? i : j;
                return greater(x, y) > z ? greater(x, y) : z;
            };
```

In the Expression 2, I was able to somehow achieve the what I wanted i.e define the function to find the greater among two numbers from the same expression itself. However, it is a statment lambda.

Is there a way to write a single lined lambda to define and use the greater of 2 numbers from within the expression of greatest itself.

Comment: You could have composed your smaller function and reused it in the larger like so: `Func<int, int, int, int> greatestNumber = (x, y, z) => greaterNumber(x, greaterNumber(y, z));`

Comment: I have written some psudo statments in here. But the target language is C#.

Anthony, with the expression you have provided, greaterNumber() needs a definition. I am just looking if it is possible to define greaterNumber in the same lambda rather than defining it outside.

Comment: I believe you will be disappointed. Indeed, I *hope* you are! As an academic exercise, I will concede this is fabulously interesting. For the point of your future coding, I would hope you opt for readability over terse cleverness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about building an array and using LINQ? Probably a bit easier to extend than working out all the logic paths with multiple inputs (untested):

```
Func<int, int, int, int> f = (x, y, z) => new[] { x, y, z }.Max();
```

EDIT: Just reread the question, it looks like you want to recurse the `greatestNumber` lambda, with just one lambda definition. I don't think you could do that, as `greatestNumber(x,y)`'s signature is different to `greatestNumber(x,y,z)`. You could probably do something more generalised with a normal function that takes a `params` argument, but that doesn't involve lambdas.

EDIT 2: As @Anthony says, creating an array is probably overkill, although it is short and a one-liner. You could simplify your Expression 2 a bit:

```
Func<int, int, int> greaterOf = (x, y) => x > y ? x : y;
Func<int, int, int, int> greaterOf = (x, y, z) => greaterOf(x, greaterOf(y, z));
```

Comment: This is a bit overkill for this problem. In yours, you're still working with only 3 inputs, but you're allocating a new array and performing an ordering operation a bit needlessly.

Comment: @Anthony I saw you mentioned composing the first function in the second one, only after I edited my answer. Whoops :-$

Comment: that's fine. Mine was merely a comment, not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

How about something along the lines of:

```
Func<int, int, int, int> greatest = (x, y, z) => Math.Max(x, Math.Max(y, z));
```

Sample test application:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<int, int, int, int> greatest = (x, y, z) => Math.Max(x, Math.Max(y, z));

        Console.WriteLine(greatest(1, 2, 3));
        Console.WriteLine(greatest(1, 3, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(greatest(2, 1, 3));
        Console.WriteLine(greatest(2, 3, 1));
        Console.WriteLine(greatest(3, 1, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(greatest(3, 2, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your writing Joshua. But my intention is to explore the ability of lambda expression. Of course we have n ways of find the greatest number. Again my interest is not on finding the greatest number, my interest is on the ability of lambda expressions.